# Can sympy simplify block matrix expressions?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Consider the following example: (I attempt to compute the matrix product involving a block matrix)

```
import sympy as sy

k, n = sy.symbols('k,n')
A = sy.MatrixSymbol("A", n, n)
B = sy.MatrixSymbol("B", n, k)
M = sy.BlockMatrix([[A * B, A]])
A.inverse() * M
```

which will output

```
A^-1*Matrix([[A*B, A]])
```

Is there a way to simplify/expand/cancel this to the more reader-friendly form of `Matrix([[B, I]])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the function [`block_collapse`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html#sympy.matrices.expressions.blockmatrix.block_collapse) which evaluates block-matrix expressions down to the level of blocks.

```
sy.block_collapse(A.inverse()*M)
```

returns `Matrix([[B, I]])`